# Is this $\underset{x<1,y<1}{\sup}f(x,y) = \underset{x<1}{\sup} \underset{y<1}{\sup}\ f(x,y) $ correct?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

$\underset{x<1,y<1}{\sup}f(x,y) = \underset{x<1}{\sup} \underset{y<1}{\sup}\ f(x,y).$

Intuitively, I think the above equation holds for all $f(x,y)$. Am I right?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: It's correct, and fairly simple to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to show this is to start with $f(x,y) = f(x,y)$ and then take the $\sup$s of one side as in
$\sup_{x',y'} f(x',y') \ge f(x,y)$ for all $x,y$. Then take the $\sup_x$, $\sup_y$ of the right hand side to get:
$\sup_{x',y'} f(x',y') \ge \sup_x \sup_yf(x,y)$.

The other direction is similar.

Here is the other direction:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x,y) &=& f(x,y) \\
f(x,y) &\le& \sup_{y'} f(x,y'), \  \ \forall y \\
f(x,y) &\le& \sup_{x'} \sup_{y'} f(x,y'), \  \ \forall y \forall x \\
\sup_{x,y} f(x,y) &\le& \sup_{x'} \sup_{y'} f(x,y')
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: How can you guarantee the inequality does not change direction when you take sup at different time? Thanks:)

Comment: Do one step at a time. If you have a set $A$, you always have $x \le \sup A$ for $x \in A$.

Comment: For the other direction, when we have $\sup_x \sup_y f(x,y)\geq f(x,y)$, we take $\sup_{x,y}$ on the right hand side. Here we cannot use the property you show above.

Comment: @E.J.: It is essentially the same procedure, I have added it to my answer above.

Comment: I think I got your point:) Thanks a lot:)))

Comment: Glad to help :-).